# PTIJ - Understanding Adar II

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I am interested in really getting a handle on Adar II as it begins but I wasn't paying attention to Adar I. Would it be better to wait until the next leap year and really pay attention in Adar I so that Adar II makes sense or is it possible to pick up with Adar II and still understand all the characters and events without being familiar with Adar I?

Is it more like Pesach Sheini which only makes sense if you actually missed the first entry in the series, or more like Yom Tov Sheini which isn't even really necessary to understand (in Israel, they ignore all those sequels except for Rosh Hashana) but if you want to get it, you have to connect it to a first day of Yom Tov?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).